# Find the exact .py window/script that corresponds to the IPython console in Spyder

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I would like to know if there is way to figure out (from the IPython console) the .py script that was used to run/execute the python commands interactively and thus got printed into the Ipython console.

For eg.

From the below screenshot, looking at the 3+3 in the Ipython console, I can see that it came in when command from untitled2.py was executed.
However when the scripts get long, and IPython output gets long and you are often shifting scripts on the left side, it can be hard to keep track.
So i was wondering if there is a way i can quickly execute some command or view some setting on Ipython console that can tell me that the above line came from untitled.py.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) There's no way to know from which Editor you're executing some portion of code, sorry.

However, you could use dedicated consoles (under `Preferences > Run > Execute in a dedicated console`) to have one console per file you execute, as long as you use <kbd>F5</kbd> to run each one of them.

Comment: Thanks @carlos, I’ll explore more on the dedicated console.

Answer (score -1):

You could edit each .py script, so the first thing it does is to print its name and functionality.

untitled2.py:

```
print('untitled2.py')
...
```